# Not able to download image in android

Tags: android, image

I always get responce NULL when call this method but in case if suppose i run in browser it display image.`public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        Bitmap bmImg;
        URL myFileUrl = null;

```
    try {
        myFileUrl = new URL("http://www.russiawear.com/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/youth_russia_usa_4e2f7f78b543c.jpg");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
        return bmImg;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}`
```

what can be problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Bitmap loadBitmap() {
    Bitmap bmQR = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = OpenHttpConnection(url);
        bmQR = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmQR;
}

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    URL url = new URL(strURL);
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            is = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return is;
}
```

Comment: Hi Gili,Please look at when i had post this question ?

Comment: @NandlalVirani - Is the comment above in reference to the fact that this question is two months old? You never accepted an answer for the question, so it doesn't seem strange to have others continue to answer it. If you did find an answer yourself, consider posting that as an answer and accepting it so others don't try and solve the problem that you've already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I just use this and its works fine in my case.

```
URL newurl;
try
{
newurl = new URL("http://www.russiawear.com/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/youth_russia_usa_4e2f7f78b543c.jpg");  
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
}
catch (IOException e)
{
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Update:**

Code for download file from URL,

```
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.russiawear.com/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/youth_russia_usa_4e2f7f78b543c.jpg"); //you can write here any link
        File file = new File("/sdcard/temp.jpg");
        /* Open a connection to that URL. */
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

        /*
         * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
         */
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        /*
         * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
         */
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1)
        {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
    }
```

Then create bitmap using file,

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/temp.jpg");
```

Comment: How can large image be downloaded in android ?

Comment: Look at my updated answer, this works perfectly for this image.

Comment: When using this code , it give me this error ---> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget